# Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundle

I keep getting the following error when running `bundle`

```
Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
```

Is this a rubygems issue or something else?

Also, I have read that adding

```
source "http://bundler-api.herokuapp.com"
```

in your Gemfile.  Will fix this problem.  So are the gems being fetching from heroku and not rubygems in this method?  How safe and stable is this?

Comment: This is solely(most definitely) underlying internet connection issue. Also this URL smells like phishing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could indicate that your connection to the internet was broken.

About the parameter to the method `source` in your `Gemfile`, I don't know nothing about that, but the url doesn't work, I recommend you avoid that. If you don't want to use a specific or particular repository to download your gems, you should use the "default" `source "http://rubygems.org"` instruction.

Comment: I waited a bit, and finally got it to work.  Thanks for the default source: rubygems that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rubygems-org/aBHBOCgH6UE/1p_Kde3BlGgJ

From what the author of that post says, the error is innocuous.

Answer (score 0):

For me, changing the source in my Gemfile to the non-HTTPS URL worked:

`http://rubygems.org`

Probably not ideal, but something with https isn't working at my location today.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is rubygems issue.

Check for these things:

1.Use the Source in Gemfile as https://rubygems.org.

2.Your Internet connection is not broken.(*Sometimes,it happens because of that.*)